# Define key when buffer is read-only

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs

I'm trying to use the keys "n" and "p" the same way as "C-n" and "C-p" when my buffer is read-only (yes, I'm lazy).

I use this code in my .emacs file :

```
(when buffer-read-only (local-set-key "n" 'next-line))
(when buffer-read-only (local-set-key "p" 'previous-line))
```

which is working when the buffer is automatically set as read-only (i.e. like within w3m) but it seems it doesn't work when I run C-x C-q (toggle-read-only). It keeps saying

```
Buffer is read-only: #<buffer buffername>
```

and I have no idea of how this could work otherwise...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your key definitions are evaluated during load of `.emacs`, whereas you want them evaluated each time a read-only file is visited, and each time `toggle-read-only` is executed. Furthermore, you want them *undone* whenever a buffer is made read-write again.

Instead of implementing all that, you can make use of the fact that Emacs already supports automatic activation of `view-mode` in read-only buffers. All you need to do is enable that functionality, and define your keys in `view-mode-map`:

```
(setq view-read-only t)     ; enter view-mode for read-only files
(define-key view-mode-map "n" 'next-line)
(define-key view-mode-map "p" 'previous-line)
```

Comment: Yeah great ! Thank you it does work now ! As you may have seen I've just begun using emacs that way... I'm gonna look further at this mode ! Thanks again ;-)