# How to define special keyboard shortcut for killing view-file buffer in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am using `view-file` to display some help information.When I press <kbd>F3</kbd> the help file is opened with `view-file`. I want to close the `view-file` buffer using the same key <kbd>F3</kbd>. But for all other buffers, the shortcut should not be defined, that is: the usual <kbd>C-x k</kbd> should still work here.

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768316/define-key-when-buffer-is-read-only/15768498#15768498

Comment: @immerrr Thanks! I tried to use `(define-key view-mode-map "<f3>" 'kill-buffer)`, but I get error `(void-variable view-mode-map)`..

Comment: You need to enclose that define-key in `(eval-after-load "view"` ... `)`, since the map won't be defined until "view" is loaded

Comment: @juanleon I tried now with `(eval-after-load "view" '(define-key view-mode-map "<f3>" 'kill-buffer))`, but I still get errors: `(error "Key sequence < f 3 > starts with non-prefix key <") define-key((keymap (104 . describe-mode) (63 . describe-mode)`...

Comment: Try the vector notation: `(define-key view-mode-map [(f3)] 'kill-buffer)`.

Comment: @juanleon Yes, now it works! Thank you very much. (Still there is minor issue: It is asking me in the minibuffer which buffer to kill, how can I avoid this question?)

Comment: @juanleon or immerrr : You may give these comments as an answer if you like..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To summarize discussion, and to solve the question of "witch buffer to kill?", here is a solution:

```lisp
(eval-after-load "view"
  '(define-key view-mode-map [(f3)] 'kill-this-buffer))
```